# ESRI IOS App Development - Have "sketchEditor.start(with:" keep previously drawn graphics when switching between drawing types

Tags: ios, swift, gis, esri

I'm new to Swift and am building a GIS app using the ArcGIS Runtime for IOS to learn more. Part of the app is giving someone the ability to draw temp graphics on top of the map. Right now when I switch between point/polyline/polygon, the graphics for whatever has been previously drawn are removed and I was wondering if there was a way to keep them there until the "CLEAR" button is clicked.

I believe the answer lies in self.sketchEditor.start(with: nil, creationMode: [draw style])

The "nil" is wiping out what was there before, but I cannot figure out what I need to replace it with to have it keep any currently drawn graphics.

Below is my code, any help would be much appreciated.

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  [name]
//
//  Created by 
//  
//

import UIKit
import ArcGIS
import MessageUI

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: AGSMapView!
    @IBOutlet weak var geometrySegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var undoBBI: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var clearBBI: UIButton!

    private var map: AGSMap!
    private var sketchEditor: AGSSketchEditor!

    private func setupMap() {
        let itemID = [portal map]
        let portal = AGSPortal(url: URL(string: "https://www.arcgis.com")!, loginRequired: false)
        let portalItem: AGSPortalItem = AGSPortalItem(portal: portal, itemID: itemID)
        mapView.map = AGSMap(item: portalItem)
    }

    private func showAlert(withStatus: String) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message:
            withStatus, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default,handler: nil))
        present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func setupLocationDisplay() {
        mapView.locationDisplay.autoPanMode = AGSLocationDisplayAutoPanMode.compassNavigation
        mapView.locationDisplay.start { [weak self] (error:Error?) -> Void in
            if let error = error {
                self?.showAlert(withStatus: error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        setupMap()

        setupLocationDisplay()

        let itemID = [portal]
        let portal = AGSPortal(url: URL(string: "https://www.arcgis.com")!, loginRequired: false)
        let portalItem: AGSPortalItem = AGSPortalItem(portal: portal, itemID: itemID)
        self.map = AGSMap(item: portalItem)

        self.sketchEditor = AGSSketchEditor()
        self.mapView.sketchEditor = self.sketchEditor

        self.sketchEditor.start(with: nil, creationMode: .unset)

        self.mapView.map = self.map
        self.mapView.interactionOptions.isMagnifierEnabled = false

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.respondToGeomChanged), name: .AGSSketchEditorGeometryDidChange, object: nil)
    }

    @objc
    func respondToGeomChanged() {
        //Enable/disable UI elements appropriately
        self.undoBBI.isSelected = self.sketchEditor.undoManager.canUndo
        self.clearBBI.isSelected = self.sketchEditor.geometry != nil && !self.sketchEditor.geometry!.isEmpty
    }

    // MARK: - Actions

    @IBAction func geometryValueChanged(_ geometrySegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl) {
        switch geometrySegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0://multipoint
            self.sketchEditor.start(with: nil, creationMode: .unset)

        case 1://freehand polyline
            self.sketchEditor.start(with: nil, creationMode: .freehandPolyline)

        case 2://freehand polygon
            self.sketchEditor.start(with: nil, creationMode: .freehandPolygon)

        case 3://multipoint
            self.sketchEditor.start(with: nil, creationMode: .multipoint)

        default:
            break
        }

        self.mapView.sketchEditor = self.sketchEditor
    }

    @IBAction func undo() {
        if self.sketchEditor.undoManager.canUndo { //extra check, just to be sure
            self.sketchEditor.undoManager.undo()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func clear() {
        self.sketchEditor.clearGeometry()
    }
}
```